# Redirect email from my email server to one hosted by Google Apps

Tags: dns, mx, email-accounts

I want to redirect email from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`. The problem is that the mail for `domain2.com` is hosted by Google Apps. All my employees have two email accounts: `employeeX@domain1.com` hosted in my office and `employeeX@domain2.com` hosted by Google Apps. I will turn off my office email servers when I'm sure that all the mail is redirected, so they only need to use one email account.

I don't know if changing the `MX` record for `domain1.com` to `mail.domain2.com` is enough, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Are you keeping activate accounts on Google apps for both domains?

Comment: I'm keeping only domain2.com as the only Google Apps domain. But I found out how to solve this: verify ownership of domain1.com to Google Apps, then make each email account have a new alias with the new domain1.com and then I can shut down domain1.com server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I will verify ownership of `domain1.com` to Google Apps, then make each email account have a new alias with the new `domain1.com` and then I can shut down domain1.com server.